# Where to find Mirth applications menu?

Tags: mirth

In our company we're using the Mirth Connect interface engine to interpret HL7 messages. For high availability we now need to move to a clustered setup, for which I'm reading [this page](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/APPLIANCE/Mirth+Connect+Clustering+Wizard). In that page we get an instruction to select the Applications menu like so:

[image]

I'm kinda puzzled here, because where does this application appear? I just have the Mirth Connect web interface and the Mirth Connect Java interface, but this seems to be a higher level system.

Could anybody help me out in where I can find this menu, or of what this screenshot is?

Comment: If you are using Mirth Connect Appliance then you should be subscribed to Mirth Support and can get a direct answer from Mirth guys.

Answer (score 1):

You are viewing documentation for the Mirth Appliance. This is an application that runs on the physical and virtual appliances sold for Mirth applications by NextGen. This requires an appliance license. Those licenses are generally sold with support contracts.